# How to make an iPhone app and exclude iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, screen, iphone-5

I'm looking at the iPhone 5 specs, and see that the screen resolution is 640x1132 or so, which would break some of my manual+storyboard interface layouts. **I'm wandering how to make an app so it would either show on iPhone 5 in 640x960 screen (with black bars), or exclude my app from sale to iPhone 5 at all**, as I do not want to worry about the interface breaking. Is this possible for existing apps?

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Apple keynote on the 12th Sept 2012, they said all current applications in the app store would run on the iPhone 5 with without a problem using the black letterbox at the top and bottom.

The way to remove the letterbox is by providing a `Default-568h@2x.png` image, like duskwuff mentioned. If its not there, the device will run the application will run at 640x960.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you include a `Default-568h@2x.png` image in your application, it will not run at full iPhone 5 resolution.